# How to set a flag in groupby with a condition in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a following dataframe

```
  code   date         time     product  tank     stock     out_value 
  123    2019-06-20   07:00    MS       1        370       350
  123    2019-06-20   07:30    HS       3        340       350
  123    2019-06-20   07:00    MS       2        340       350
  123    2019-06-20   07:30    HS       4        340       350
  123    2019-06-20   08:00    MS       1        470       350
  123    2019-06-20   08:30    HS       3        450       350
  123    2019-06-20   08:00    MS       2        470       350
  123    2019-06-20   08:30    HS       4        490       350
  123    2019-06-20   09:30    HS       4        0         350
  234    2019-06-20   09:30    HS       1        200       350
```

I want to find out which `stock` values are less than `out_value` in above dataframe excluding `0` value. 
e.g. at `07:30` for ro code `123` on date `2019-06-20` for product `HS` there are two tanks `3` and `4`, so if stocks for both the tanks are below `out_value` then flag is set to `1`.

My desired dataframe would be

```
  code   date         time     product  tank     stock     out_value    flag
  123    2019-06-20   07:00    MS       1        370       350          0
  123    2019-06-20   07:30    HS       3        340       350          1
  123    2019-06-20   07:00    MS       2        340       350          0
  123    2019-06-20   07:30    HS       4        340       350          1
  123    2019-06-20   08:00    MS       1        470       350          0
  123    2019-06-20   08:30    HS       3        450       350          0
  123    2019-06-20   08:00    MS       2        470       350          0
  123    2019-06-20   08:30    HS       4        490       350          0
  123    2019-06-20   09:30    HS       4        0         350          0
  234    2019-06-20   09:30    HS       1        200       350          1
```

How can I do it in pandas?

Comment: `MS` at `07:00` at is not marked as 1 because tank=1 is not less than out_value correct?

Comment: @Erfan That's correct. If one product is mapped in one or more tanks then all the tanks should be less than `out_value` field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If need check difference with non `0` values and then check all `True` values per groups with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html):

```
df['flag'] = ((df['stock']<df['out_value']) & (df['stock'] !=0))

df['flag'] = df.groupby(['code','date','time','product'])['flag'].transform('all').astype(int)
print (df)
   code        date   time product  tank  stock  out_value  flag
0   123  2019-06-20  07:00      MS     1    370        350     0
1   123  2019-06-20  07:30      HS     3    340        350     1
2   123  2019-06-20  07:00      MS     2    340        350     0
3   123  2019-06-20  07:30      HS     4    340        350     1
4   123  2019-06-20  08:00      MS     1    470        350     0
5   123  2019-06-20  08:30      HS     3    450        350     0
6   123  2019-06-20  08:00      MS     2    470        350     0
7   123  2019-06-20  08:30      HS     4    490        350     0
8   123  2019-06-20  09:30      HS     4      0        350     0
9   234  2019-06-20  09:30      HS     1    200        350     1
```

Or if need test only difference, test per groups and last chain with mask for test non `0` values:

```
df['flag'] = df['stock']<df['out_value']
mask = df.groupby(['code','date','time','product'])['flag'].transform('all')
df['flag'] = (mask & (df['stock'] !=0)).astype(int)
```

Comment: What does transform do in this case?

Comment: @Neil - it return Series with same size like original `DataFrame` - so possible assign new column

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
df['flag'] = (df.assign(flag=(df.stock<df.out_value)&(df.stock>0))
                .groupby(['code', 'date', 'time', 'product'], as_index=False)['flag']
                .transform(all)
                .astype(int))

df

   code        date   time product  tank  stock  out_value  flag
0   123  2019-06-20  07:00      MS     1    370        350     0
1   123  2019-06-20  07:30      HS     3    340        350     1
2   123  2019-06-20  07:00      MS     2    340        350     0
3   123  2019-06-20  07:30      HS     4    340        350     1
4   123  2019-06-20  08:00      MS     1    470        350     0
5   123  2019-06-20  08:30      HS     3    450        350     0
6   123  2019-06-20  08:00      MS     2    470        350     0
7   123  2019-06-20  08:30      HS     4    490        350     0
8   123  2019-06-20  09:30      HS     4      0        350     0
9   234  2019-06-20  09:30      HS     1    200        350     1
```

Comment: hmmm, assign vs `df['flag'] =` is too small difference, what do you think?

Comment: @jezrael It took me quite some time to write this. And similarity isn't coincidence - I read your answers all the time, you got into my head :)

Answer (score 0):

you could do, it gives(I guess) the right result for the dataframe you provided, but I'm not sure if that's what you want.

```py
df['flag'] = ((df['stock']<df['out_value']) & (df['stock'] !=0)).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, it is quite unclear what you're asking. If you want to flag as `1`, all the rows which has `stock` below to `out_value`, except if they are `0`, you can do...

```
df['flag'] = 0
df.loc[(df['stock'] < df['out_value']) & (df['stock'] != 0), 'flag'] = 1
```